# MonoTouch: UIWeb not playing YouTube Embedded videos

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

In our app we host a UIWebView control in a UINavigation controller and have it go get web pages. These pages have embedded YouTube videos.

On an iPad it works fine, on an iPhone the video pops open then flicks and dies returning to the app and the app can continue fine so it's not the app crashing.

This is the **iPhone** error I get from the Console (not super helpful):

```
 Nov  8 18:04:37 backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilesafari[0xf377]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
 Nov  8 18:04:37 ReportCrash[7703] <Notice>: 
          Not saving suspended-only Jetsam log because already dumped today.
```

In the **Simulator** I get this:

```
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
setting movie path: http://o-o---preferred---sn-nx57yne7---v23---lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=2-
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
setting movie path: http://o-o---preferred---sn-nx57yne7---v23---lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=2-Jx_RQQ4Hs&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&fexp=90331
[MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you navigate to one of these pages in plain Safari?

Comment: hi jonathan, no it works fine in safari.

Comment: Hmm, I guess safari normally dumps in the morning?  jk, this is a strange one.  Are you navigating to a Youtube page, or a page you guys have written?  I wonder if a standard Youtube page works.

Comment: The link it opens is http://www.youtube.com/embed/wI8t3wWsoQU